# My function solving for average value delivers random values

Tags: c, algorithm, average, pic, mikroc

I'm using MikroC to try and program a PIC4550 to retrieve data from pH Sensor. The program consist of retrieving data 40 times and calculating its average value with function Average below

```
double Average(int* arr, int number)
{
    int i;
    int ave;
    int sum = arr[0];
    for(i = 0;i<number;i++)
    {
        sum=sum+arr[i];
    }
    ave = sum/number;
    return ave;
}
```

My problem is it delivers random values very far from the right answer most of the time. For example, the right answer is 633 but it delivers -185. Can anyone point out my mistake? thanks. My whole code is below

```
#define volt 5.00 //system voltage
#define arraylength 40 // number of data collection
#define offsetph 5   //deviate compensate

double Average(int*, int);

void main() {
     float ph_res=0;
     float pHsensor_output[40];
     double avepH;
     double pHvoltage;
     float offsetpH=0.38;  //change to actual pH offset
     float pHlevel;
     char testing[20];
     char pher[20];
     int i;
     int pH_index=0;
     UART1_Init(9600);
     ADCON1=0x00;
     CMCON=7;

     TRISA=0xFF;


   while(1){
    UART1_Write_Text("Reading pH....\r\n");
     for(i = 0; i<40; i++) {
            pHsensor_output[i] = ADC_Read(1);
            sprintf(testing,"READING: %.2f\r\n",pHsensor_output[i]);
            UART1_Write_Text(testing);
            delay_us(1000);
        }
        avepH = Average(pHsensor_output, 40);
        sprintf(testing,"AVG: %f\r\n",avepH);
        UART1_Write_Text(testing);
        pHvoltage = avepH*5/1024;
        pHlevel = 3.5*pHvoltage+offsetph;
        if(pHlevel!=pH_res){
            pH_res = pHlevel;

        }
             sprintf(pher,"pH: %f\r\n",pH_res);
            UART1_Write_Text(pher);

     delay_ms(2000);
       } }
double Average(int* arr, int number)
{
    int i;
    int ave;
    int sum = arr[0];
    for(i = 0;i<number;i++)
    {
        sum=sum+arr[i];
    }
    ave = sum/number;
    return ave;
}
```

Comment: Two issues at least: You sum up `arr[0]` twice and you do an integer division, cutting off any possible remainder. Depending on how large your input values are, you might suffer from overflow as well (they need at average be smaller than `INT_MAX / 40` and larger than `INT_MIN / 40`).

Comment: How big is an `int`?  Signed `int` overflow is undefined behavior in C, and `sum=sum+arr[i];` seems quite likely to overflow when it's in a loop like that.

Comment: You likely have undefined behavior from signed integer overflow.  Once you hit that, any output is totally meaningless.

Comment: `pHsensor_output` is a `float` and you're passing it into a function expecting an array of `int` that is very likely your issue (any compiler warnings?).  Try printing out the values you're summing within `Average()`.

Comment: Hello, a sample output is 665 is the right answer. So 665x40=26400, far from the limit so I dont think it's an overflow problem.

Comment: And given `double Average(int* arr, int number)`, why are you passing `float pHsensor_output[40];` to a function that expects an `int` array?

Comment: Average() is defined as returning a double, however, the function returns an int.

Comment: @jmq The int will be promoted to double, so that's not an issue – as long as the int is able to hold the value that should be calculated, of course. But if not, the whole trouble starts already much earlier...

Comment: @Aconcagua - You are correct, but I was assuming that the int would not be able to hold the value that should be calculated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Several of the comments have pointed out that you are at risk of overflow during your summation.  If this is a 16-bit machine, INT_MAX is 32767.  As per your example, you're not getting close to this, but it's something to be careful of.

Anyway, you're collecting values into an array of `floats`:

```
 float pHsensor_output[40];
 ...
 pHsensor_output[i] = ADC_Read(1);
```

But later passing that to a function expecting an array of `int`s:

```
double Average(int* arr, int number)
...
  avepH = Average(pHsensor_output, 40);
```

(The fact that `Average` calculates with `int`s and returns a `double` means you *might* get a truncated answer, but it's not the problem here.)

Your computer is now looking at a pattern of bits that might be '633' when viewed as a float, but almost certainly won't be when viewed as an integer.  So who knows what the result will be when you take the average of them?!

Try changing your function to something like:

```
double Average(float* arr, int number)
{
    int i;
    double ave;
    double sum = 0.0; // NOTE: not arr[0];
    for(i = 0;i<number;i++)
    {
        sum=sum+arr[i];
    }
    ave = sum/number;
    return ave;
}
```

Addendum: your compiler *really* should have complained about this.  Did it really keep quiet?  GCC barfs immediately.

```
error: cannot convert ‘float*’ to ‘int*’ for argument ‘1’ to ‘double Average(int*, int)’
```

---

Edit: It's always nice to *understand* by seeing, so I tried a little example.  Mine is a desktop, not a PIC so `int` is 32-bits not 16, but hopefully the point is the same....

```
int main()
{
    union {
        float my_float;
        int my_int;
    } hack;

    printf ("sizeof(float) %lu, sizeof(int) %lu\n", sizeof(float), sizeof(int));

    hack.my_float = 633.0;
    printf( "%f -> %d\n", hack.my_float, hack.my_int );

    int sum = 40 * hack.my_int;
    int average = sum / 40;

    printf( "sum %d  -->  %d\n", sum, average );

    return 0;
}
```

Yields:

```
sizeof(float) 4, sizeof(int) 4
633.000000 -> 1142833152
sum -1531314176  -->  -38282854
```

What this 'shows' is that a nice `float` becomes a crazy `int` (when the same pattern of bits is looked at differently<sup>1</sup>), and after that, all bets are off.  Clearly, the summation overflows, and hence the average comes out negative;  not what you'd have expected at all!

<sup>1</sup>  The 'union hack' I used in my example says to the computer: "take the memory location holding a `float` and look at the exact same bits but pretend it's an `int`.  This is what's happening when you pass a pointer to some floats to a function expecting a pointer to ints.

But if you do an assignment 'cleanly' you get what you'd expect:

```
    int nice_int = hack.my_float;  // 633.0
    printf( "good %f  ->  %d\n", hack.my_float, nice_int );
```

yields:

```
good 633.000000  ->  633
```

Comment: Alternatively, you could set sum to arr[0] and start your loop at 1.

Comment: Thanks. I thought it would be okay to transfer the values across data types. Your solution worked great